# Why is it expensive to store binary data on Ethereum blockchain

Tags: storage, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, nft

i have completed my Solidity contract, which I want to use to upload a PDF/JPG file onto the Ethereum Blockchain. I just calculated the cost at around .70 USD per hour (@720 hours per month, the cost is an astonishing USD 504). Can you help with these questions please?

1. What is the most cost-effective way to store a 1MB file on the Blockchain
2. Would you recommend IPFS? Is it really free?
3. Is there additional cost every time I check if the file is authentic? Based on user-uploaded hash and comparing with the uploaded hash or file
4. Can you please help in suggesting a solution where the cost of storing and checking is kept to a minimum?

Sorry, too many questions. But any help is super appreciated.  Thanks

I have checked on the Web to see the costs. It varies from USD 0.3 to USD 0.8 per hour. I only want to upload a small file on the blockchain and later check if tha file is authentic by comparing to the user-provided file.

Comment: In my experience, the blockchain only requires a gas fee to make transactions, and storage should be free, mainly because the blockchain can't charge you anything without using a smart contract to transfer funds, but I also have no experience uploading images to Ethereum so I'm not sure.

Comment: No, storage is not free.  If you want an alternative, you can throw events with your data in them instead of using storage and have the graph index them, but even so theres no guarantee they will persist with time

Comment: Filecoin and storj help pin,  but IPFS data is sensorable, vs block chain data, is not.  Chances are the data your posting isn't going to be censored so IPFS should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most cost-effective way to store a 1MB file on the Blockchain

Use a chain specialised to storage like Arweave, Filecoin or Storj. Ethereum is designed for financial applications, not for storing files. You should not use Ethereum for something it is not designed for.

> Would you recommend IPFS? Is it really free?

IPFS is not persistent storage but a cache layer. Think it as a BitTorrent alternative. You still need to pay to host somewhere.

> Is there additional cost every time I check if the file is authentic? Based on user-uploaded hash and comparing with the uploaded hash or file

For all blockchain systems I know at the moment, reads are free.